# sony DCR-SX40 with skype?

Tags: skype, camera

Can I use my Sony DCR-SX40 with Skype? Sony website says driver is included in XP. When connecting, USB Connect shows up in two modes. One looks as if it is a "hard drive" the other doesn't seem to do anything. Skype does not detect any web cameras when attached in either mode.